# complex query as source

Tags: ssis

I have a query to be used as source. but this is a huge query containing lot of temp tables created and finally joining which brings select data. So I used Script Task for this query which works perfectly. Is there any other way instead of Script task ?

Comment: That's a pretty open-ended statement.  One option is to execute the task directly from your database engine as a stored procedure.  However, if you are executing the stored procedure from within the same SQL Server that contains the SSIS package that you are executing, I'm not so user that it would provide any significant perfomance increase.

Comment: @RLH, you can't use stored procs with temp tables as a source. It won't recognize the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CTEs instead of temp tables you can directly use it as a source query in the OLE DB Source.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could keep your current logic in a script task but then insert the data from the final select into a temporary (physical) table.  The data flow task could then do a simple select directly on that temp table.